# Angular ui grid make a non editable row into editable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to add edit, trash icons to Angular UI grid. On click on a particular row I want to allow the user to only edit the particular row.

[image]

Is there any api method available which will make non editable row into editable row on fly? I want to disable the feature of making ui grid editable if user double clicks it as well.

Comment: Could you please post some code so that we know what you are upto?

Comment: Check out this plunker - http://embed.plnkr.co/VO6F3vlOOwaudfi3RSVA/

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to the ui-grid [201 Edit Feature](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable)

if you want to edit the row, please use the method:`cellEditableCondition`